# Run a certain macro everytime when calculate sheet/workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a vba event to run a certain macro everytime when sheet/workbook is calculated (F9/Shift+F9).

I have code below for workbook, macro 'Fillalldata' is working if I manually run this macro. But nothing happened if I calculate sheet/workbook.
Please help out.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Call Fillalldata

End Sub
```

The code for Fillalldata is as below

```
 Sub Fillalldata()
 'Fill sheet Tracker, Packaging tracking & FINI tracking completed
 Dim wkbNPI As Workbook
Dim wksPT As Worksheet
Dim wksTK As Worksheet
Dim wksFINI As Worksheet
Dim wksGS As Worksheet

Set wkbNPI = ThisWorkbook
Set wksPT = wkbNPI.Sheets("Packaging tracking")
Set wksTK = wkbNPI.Sheets("Tracker")
Set wksFINI = wkbNPI.Sheets("FINI tracking")
Set wksGS = wkbNPI.Sheets("GensightExport")

Dim Volumn As Long
Dim cansize As Single

Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

Dim rw As Long
    rw = wksTK.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim lrw3 As Long
    lrw3 = wksPT.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim lrw4 As Long
    lrw4 = wksFINI.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

Dim PTarray As Variant
Dim FNarray As Variant

Dim i As Long


 'Fill tracker sheet

 For i = 6 To rw

Dim Project As Long
Project = wksTK.Cells(i, 1)
wksTK.Cells(i, 2) = wf.VLookup(Project, wksGS.Range("B:BI"), 3, False)
wksTK.Cells(i, 3) = wf.VLookup(Project, wksGS.Range("B:BI"), 2, False)
wksTK.Cells(i, 4) = wf.VLookup(Project, wksGS.Range("B:BI"), 7, False)
wksTK.Cells(i, 32) = wf.VLookup(Project, wksGS.Range("B:BI"), 60, False)
wksTK.Cells(i, 33) = wf.VLookup(Project, wksGS.Range("B:BI"), 9, False)
wksTK.Cells(i, 34) = wf.VLookup(Project, wksGS.Range("B:BI"), 4, False)
wksTK.Cells(i, 35) = wf.VLookup(Project, wksGS.Range("B:BI"), 16, False)
wksTK.Cells(i, 36) = wf.VLookup(Project, wksGS.Range("B:BI"), 17, False)
wksTK.Cells(i, 37) = wf.VLookup(Project, wksGS.Range("B:BI"), 18, False)
wksTK.Cells(i, 38) = wf.VLookup(Project, wksGS.Range("B:BI"), 19, False)

On Error Resume Next
 Next i


 'Fill FINI sheet

FNarray = wksFINI.Range("A7:AG" & lrw4)

For i = 1 To UBound(FNarray)

Dim PN As Long
PN = FNarray(i, 4) 'Project number

    If Len(CStr(PN)) = 4 Then

    FNarray(i, 3) = wf.VLookup(PN, wksGS.Range("D:BI"), 58, False)
    FNarray(i, 5) = wf.VLookup(PN, wksTK.Range("B:E"), 4, False)
    FNarray(i, 12) = wf.VLookup(PN, wksGS.Range("D:H"), 5, False)
    FNarray(i, 30) = wf.VLookup(PN, wksTK.Range("B:AL"), 37, False)

    Else

    FNarray(i, 3) = wf.VLookup(PN, wksGS.Range("B:BI"), 60, False)
    FNarray(i, 5) = wf.VLookup(PN, wksTK.Range("A:E"), 5, False)
    FNarray(i, 12) = wf.VLookup(PN, wksGS.Range("B:H"), 7, False)
    FNarray(i, 30) = wf.VLookup(PN, wksTK.Range("A:AL"), 38, False)
    End If

    If FNarray(i, 13) <> 0 And FNarray(i, 15) <> 0 Then 'when FNaray =?, how to avoid this?

    FNarray(i, 14) = FNarray(i, 15) / FNarray(i, 13)

    On Error Resume Next

    End If
Next i

wksFINI.Range("A7:AG" & lrw4) = FNarray

 'Fill PT sheet
    PTarray = wksPT.Range("A7:AG" & lrw3)
Dim ID As Long

For i = 1 To UBound(PTarray)

    ID = PTarray(i, 1)

    If Len(CStr(ID)) = 4 Then
        PTarray(i, 2) = wf.VLookup(ID, wksTK.Range("B:E"), 4, False)                'vlookup Project nr
        PTarray(i, 5) = wf.VLookup(ID, wksTK.Range("B:C"), 2, False)              'vlookup Project type
        PTarray(i, 6) = wf.VLookup(ID, wksTK.Range("B:AF"), 31, False)             'vlookup Project stage
    Else
        PTarray(i, 2) = wf.VLookup(ID, wksTK.Range("A:E"), 5, False)
        PTarray(i, 5) = wf.VLookup(ID, wksTK.Range("B:D"), 3, False)
        PTarray(i, 6) = wf.VLookup(ID, wksTK.Range("A:AF"), 32, False)
    End If

    If ID <> 0 Then

        cansize = wf.VLookup(PTarray(i, 3), wksFINI.Range("H:M"), 6, False)                                           'vlookup can size in FINI sheet
        PTarray(i, 8) = cansize
        PTarray(i, 9) = wf.VLookup(PTarray(i, 3), wksFINI.Range("H:L"), 5, False)                                           'vlookup project type
        Volumn = wf.VLookup(PTarray(i, 3), wksFINI.Range("H:P"), 9, False)

        PTarray(i, 18) = Volumn / cansize                   'Annual pcs=vlookup volumn and divide by can size
        On Error Resume Next

    End If


Next i

wksPT.Range("A7:AG" & lrw3) = PTarray

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show the code of `Fillalldata`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I have added in, but I don't think it's really relevant

Comment: Note that the `Workbook_SheetCalculate` only triggers on F9 or Shift+F9 if there is something to calculate. It does not trigger just because you press F9. If there is nothing to calculate even pressing F9 doesn't trigger the event. Also note that every write action to any cell might trigger another `Workbook_SheetCalculate` so you can easily end up in a loop. Turn off `Application.EnableEvents = False` before calling `Fillalldata` and enable them afterwards.

Comment: Note that using `On Error Resume Next` just hides all error messages but doesn't fix the errors. They still occur but you just don't see them (it's like closing your eyes). Remove that line and fix your errors.

Comment: Also note that the code *must* be in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, thanks for your kind suggestion. but my aim is  to automatically run 'Fillalldata' macro. basically user of this tool need to firstly manually input some key data and then run 'Fillalldata' macro to find other relevant data. Except calculate event, do you maybe have any other suggestion?

Comment: @Rory yes I do put in this workbook module

Comment: When you want your code running on a calculate on your sheet, add a volatile function to it. =NOW()  for example. F9 will nog trigger a calculate. (But really have a look at the suggested comments)

Comment: Using Workbook_SheetCalculate is unreliable, since it relies on there being something to recalculate and it can be triggered when you don't want it to happen.  Disabling events should only be used if you have rock solid error handling to make sure that if you disable your events, then they ALWAYS get enabled.  I would suggest a simple solution such as adding a custom ribbon with a button to execute your code only when you truly want to have it executed.  There are several CustomUI tools out there that can help you build the ribbon,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use a button on your sheet that the user can press to run `FillAllData`.

Alternatively you could use the `Workbook_SheetChange` event to check if a value was entered in a specific range, to then trigger the `FillAllData` procedure.
**But I recommend to use a button for that, since this is action that the user will easily understand.**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then 'runs only if range A1 was changed
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        FillAllData

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the kind of code that gives me nightmares...  If FillAllData errors out, then you just disabled events with nothing to re-enable them.  Now any event-driven code just got switched off and won't run.  Also, if you are gong to use a button to call a macro, then it should be placed on ribbon, not a sheet. Putting it on sheet allows it to be deleted by deleting the sheet and forces the user to be on that specific sheet to execute the code ("I don't see any "Update" button.").

Comment: @FrankBall good points. But in a good and reliable code of `FillAllData` there should be no uncaught VBA error at all. VBA code that throws unexpected errors and stops in the editor is no good code. So your scenario should only occur during testing/debugging but not in the final productive. Then `FillAllData`will always return here and enable events. Good practice: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling). • I agree that a ribbon button would be a nice solution, while users might not look for an "update" button in the ribbon either.

Comment: I can break that FillAllData function by simply renaming a sheet.  ALL code should be considered "breakable" and responsible programming demands that you always handle those kind of scenarios.  Don't get me started on data validation....

Comment: @FrankBall but `FillAllData` should catch this kind of error instead of ending in a non expected state in VB Editor. For example if an error occurs in `FillAllData` throw a message box and exit the procedure would be enough to make it safe.

Comment: ALL code should be considered breakable when using this kind of functionality.  It's foolish to think that just because you think that a function isn't breakable that someone else can't find a way to cause it to fail.  I could break this particular function by renaming sheets, deleting sheets, adding error vales to the VLOOKUP ranges, etc.  There are a plethora ways to break code and any time you think that you've covered all your bases, a user will come along and do something completely unexpected, so responsible code should always handle these kind of situations.

Comment: @FrankBall That's just not true. If a proper error handling is implemented in `FindAllData` you will not be able to break it. A good error handling would catch *all* unexpected errors and for example show a message box or/and log them. But this will not break the code execution at all. See [this strategy](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#An_Example_of_using_this_strategy). This will show a massage but you will not be able to  break it and end in the code editor.